# UI Automation with White issue finding childs

Tags: c#, user-interface, automation, white-framework

For some reason I am getting a run-time error from White.Core when trying to locate a Window child from its parent.

**ERROR displayed:**

```
White.Core.Mappings.ControlDictionaryException: Could not find TestControl for ControlType=window and FrameworkId:Win32
at White.Core.Mappings.ControlDictionary.GetTestControlType(ControlType controlType, String frameWorkId, Boolean isNativeControl)
at White.Core.Mappings.ControlDictionary.GetTestType(String className, ControlType controlType, String frameworkId, String name, Boolean isNativeControl)
at White.Core.Mappings.ControlDictionary.GetTestType(AutomationElement automationElement)
at White.Core.Factory.DictionaryMappedItemFactory.Create(AutomationElement automationElement, ActionListener actionListener)
at White.Core.Factory.DictionaryMappedItemFactory.Create(AutomationElement automationElement, ActionListener actionListener, Type customItemType)
at White.Core.Factory.PrimaryUIItemFactory.Create(SearchCriteria searchCriteria, ActionListener actionListener)
at White.Core.UIItems.Container.NonCachedContainerItemFactory.Find(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
at White.Core.UIItems.Container.ContainerItemFactory.Get(SearchCriteria searchCriteria, ActionListener uiItemActionListener)
at White.Core.Sessions.NullWindowSession.Get(ContainerItemFactory containerItemFactory, SearchCriteria searchCriteria, ActionListener actionListener)
at White.Core.UIItems.Container.CurrentContainerItemFactory.Find(SearchCriteria searchCriteria, WindowSession windowSession)
at White.Core.UIItems.UIItemContainer.Get(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at White.Core.UIItems.UIItemContainer.Get(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
at ICOWrapper.Form1.wasUserLoggedIn(String id1, String id2)
at ICOWrapper.Form1.button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The current structure that I am trying to navigate is the following:

Main Window->Panel->Window

**and I am using the following method in C#**

```
        public Boolean wasUserLoggedIn(string id1, string id2)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        var mdiClient = window.MdiChild(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Pane).AndAutomationId(id1));
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        var selectPatient = (Window)mdiClient.Get(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Window).AndAutomationId(id2));
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        return selectPatient != null? true: false;
    }
```

**and calling the method as follow:**

```
Boolean wasFound = wasUserLoggedIn("40960", "40961");
```

**UIspy objects used for identify ControlType and AutomationID:**

```
AutomationId: 40960
ControlType: ControlType.Pane
Name: 
HelpText: 
Bounding rectangle: 8,78,900,581
ClassName: MDIClient
IsOffScreen: False
FrameworkId: Win32
ProcessId: 5964


AutomationId: 40961
ControlType: ControlType.Window
Name: Home
HelpText: 
Bounding rectangle: 8,59,900,600
ClassName: ClaWin01000000H_2
IsOffScreen: False
FrameworkId: Win32
ProcessId: 5964
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend upgrading to `TestStack.White` rather than the old White library.

The problem is that you are not supposed to use `.Get()` to resolve windows. For MDI applications you should use `MdiChild()`, if it is a `modal` window, use `.ModalWindow()` on the `parent` window or go back to the application then use `Window()` to get the window.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Pane` a descendant of the `Window` `AutomationElement`? The `Window` you're trying to find might not be in focus.